# size deduction in a templated c-string wrapper

Tags: c++, arrays, template-argument-deduction

Why doesn't this work :

```
#include <cstring>

template<size_t sz>
struct wstr {
    wchar_t _str[sz];

    wstr(const wchar_t source[sz]) {
        wcscpy_s(_str, source);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    wstr ws = L"Hello"; //needs template argument

    return 0;
}
```

`L"Hello"` is known it's a `const wchar_t[6]`.

Comment: Type of `source` is `wchar_t  const *`, not an array, even though it is declared as one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For template deduction to work on arrays, you need to take the argument as a reference to the array.

```
wstr(const wchar_t (&source)[sz]) { ... }
```

Comment: It looks good but it still doesn't compile - size is not deduced.

Comment: @pink tell your compiler to use C++17.  I am staring at your code, modified to use a reference there, and compiling.

Comment: that's probably it (using C++14).